# how to Convert to image and to stdout

Tags: php, bash, stdout, ghostscript

I use php and ghostscript to convert pdf to image and show

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET['page'])) die;
$numPage=$_GET['page'];
header('Content-type:image/jpeg');
system("gs ".
"-dNOPAUSE ".
"-sDEVICE=jpeg ".
"-dFirstPage={$numPage} ".
"-dLastPage={$numPage} ".
"-sOutputFile=%stdout ".
"-dJPEGQ=90 ".
"-r100x100 ".
"-q file.pdf ".
"-c quit");
?>
```

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `passthru` instead of `system`
   According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) `This function[passthru()] should be used in place of exec() or system() when the output from the Unix command is binary data which needs to be passed directly back to the browser.`
2. change `%stdout` to `-`
   [gs man page](http://www.bigbiz.com/cgi-bin/manpage?1%20ghostscript):

   `You  can  also  send  output to stdout for piping with the switch`

   ```
           -sOutputFile=-
   ```

the code below should fix it.

```
<?php

if(empty($_GET['page'])) die;

$numPage=$_GET['page'];

header('Content-type:image/jpeg');

passthru("gs ".
"-dNOPAUSE ".
"-sDEVICE=jpeg ".
"-dFirstPage={$numPage} ".
"-dLastPage={$numPage} ".
"-sOutputFile=- ".
"-dJPEGQ=90 ".
"-r100x100 ".
"-q file.pdf ".
"-c quit");

?>
```